# Search and update gridview not working c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a gridview for displaying data. Whenever I made an update in data and press update button my data is updated. But when I search a record from gridview with textbox and then update, it is not working.
Here is my display data code:

```
        SqlDataAdapter sda;
        DataTable dt;
        SqlCommandBuilder scb;
        DataSet ds;
        SqlConnection con8 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=RAMISHA-PC;Initial Catalog=sales;Integrated Security=True");
        public void display_data()
        {
            try
            {
                con8.Open();
                sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM category", con8);
                ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
                dt = new DataTable("product update");
                sda.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                dataGridView1.Columns["com_id"].ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Comp Id";
                dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Company Name";
                dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 200;
                dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 100;
                dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Category Name";
                dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 200;
                con8.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is some error. Please try again!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
          }
```

Here is my update code on button click event:

```
  private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
           sda.Update(dt);
           display_data();
         }
```

Here is my textbox search code:

```
private void TxtSearch_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
            {
                DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
                dv.RowFilter = string.Format("com_name like '%{0}%' ", txtSearch.Text);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
            }
        }
```

Now when I do search a record is filterd and I want to update it. But when I update and press update button it does not effect. Please help me where I am wrong?

Comment: Did you check database after pressing update does records updated in tables ?

Comment: Your search code is *replacing* the datasource with that table you create from the DefaultView, which has nothing to do with the DT used in the update code.  Also, if you configure the DataAdapter properly you do not need to recreate the commandbuilder over and over nor do you need to manage the connection like that, neither should you have to call `display_data()` over and over to create everything

Comment: @DanijelBoksan yes I have checked. No update in database

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp What are you exactly suggesting me to do?

Comment: So first you need to manage that your code updating database.  Here are some example how to do it: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b846a8/database-updation-from-datagridview/